# MySQL: Conditional WHERE blocks

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables that I want to `INNER JOIN`, thereby I also have some user-input as conditions. The tables are (simplified) as follows:

```
# Table: node
- nid
- title  

#Table: field_min_hours_value
- entity_id (corresponds to node.nid)
- field_min_hours_value

#Table: field_max_hours_value
- entity_id (corresponds to node.nid)
- field_max_hours_value
```

I need to fetch the nodes with a few user input values, first and foremost `@max` and `@min` hours, these can both have values between `-1` and `40`. When one is set to `-1` it should be ignored and not be used.

A node can have both `field_min_hours_value` and `field_max_hours_value` values filled then it indicates it can vary between `field_min_hours_value` and `field_max_hours_value` hours.

If only `field_min_hours_value` is set, then `field_max_hours_value` will contain `0` and combined they indicate this node only have one possible duration.

I tried something like the query underneith, but creates errors, but I think it does illustrate somewhat what I need to do. I want to fetch all the nodes between `@min` and `@max`, but also want to be considering that one or both of those values can be empty (`-1`) and then I need all the nodes.

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, min.field_min_hours_value, max.field_max_hours_value
  FROM node n 
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_max_hours max 
    ON n.nid = max.entity_id
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_min_hours min 
    ON n.nid = min.entity_id
  # Use the min value
  IF @min != -1 THEN
     WHERE 
       max.field_max_hours_value >= @min
       OR (max.field_max_hours_value = 0 AND min.field_min_hours_value >= @min) # Needed for when there is no max_hours set in the node
  END IF
  # Use the max value
  IF @max != -1 THEN 
     AND 
       # Use the max value
       (min.field_min_hours_value <= @max)
  END IF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another OR condition in your WHERE:

```
WHERE (@min = -1 OR 
    max.field_max_hours_value >= @min
        OR (max.field_max_hours_value = 0 AND min.field_min_hours_value >= @min) 
        # Needed for when there is no max_hours set in the node    
) AND (@max = -1 OR
    (min.field_min_hours_value <= @max)
    # Use the max value
)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, sadly I've tried this in about the same form like an hour ago. Seeing your example, I noticed that I did it then with a `!=` for the "-1 condition" instead of `=`. Thanks, I'm using this axactly as written by you, and also thanks for the wake up call. Now it's time for the weekend... ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use this sql

```
 select n.nid, n.title, min.field_min_hours_value, max.field_max_hours_value
 from node n
    left outer join field_max_hours_value max on max.entity_id = n.nid
    left outer join field_min_hours_value min on min.entity_id = n.nid
    where (min.field_min_hours_value <= @min or -1 = @min)
      and (max.field_max_hours_value >= @max or -1 = @max)
```

Use

```
ifnull(min.field_min_hours_value, -1), ifnull(max.field_max_hours_value, -1) 
if you want to get null values as -1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT n.nid, n.title,
(case when field_min_hours_value is null then 0 
      when field_min_hours_value is not null then field_min_hours_value end) 
as field_min_hours_value,
(case when max.field_max_hours_value is null then 0 
      when max.field_max_hours_value is not null then max.field_max_hours_value end) 
as max.field_max_hours_value 
FROM node n 
left join field_data_field_min_hours min ON n.nid = min.entity_id 
left join field_data_field_max_hours max ON n.nid = max.entity_id) as p 
where (p.field_max_hours_value>=@min or p.field_max_hours_value =0 and 
p.field_min_hours_value>=@min))and p.field_min_hours_value<@max
```

Source SQL coding :)